# strings prefix isomorphism with max length

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

string s1 and s2 are isomorphic means——
if we make the two string into rings,the two rings are the same. 
Example:"abcd" and "cdab" are isomorphic
”abcd“ and "dcba" are not isomrphic
"cdab" and "abdc" are not too.

Now you have two strings, output a max length make the prefixs of the two strings with the length isomorphic.

Example:"abcdx" and "cdabz"
the max length is 4.

Time complexity as low as possible.

PS:  The length of the two strings are the same

Here is a wrong solution,but passed all test

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#define MAXN 2000001
#define MOD 100000007
using namespace std;
char str1[MAXN],str2[MAXN];
int next1[MAXN],next2[MAXN],n;
int p[27][26],ct=0;
void getnext(char *s1,char *s2,int* next){
    next[0]=0;
    int pos=2,cnd=0;
    while(pos<n){
        if(s1[pos-1]==s2[cnd])
        {++cnd;next[pos]=cnd;++pos;}
        else if(cnd>0)cnd=next[cnd];
        else {next[pos]=0;++pos;} 
    }
}
void getpri(){
    int cnt=0;
    for(int i=2;cnt<26;i++){
        bool flag=true;
        for(int j=2;j*j<=i;j++)if(i%j==0){flag=false;break;}
        if(flag)p[cnt][ct++]=i;
        if(ct==26)++cnt,ct=0;
    }
}
string s1,s2,str;
bool check(int p){
    str=string(s1.substr(0,p)+s1.substr(0,p));
    int res=str.find(s2.substr(0,p));
    if(res!=-1)return true;
    return false;
}
stack<int>stk;
int main()
{
    freopen("beyond.in","r",stdin);
    freopen("beyond.out","w",stdout);
    getpri();
    scanf("%d\n%s\n%s",&n,str1,str2);
    s1=str1;s2=str2;
    getnext(str1,str2,next1);
    getnext(str2,str1,next2);
    int ans=0;
    long long h1=1,h2=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(i>0){
            h1=(h1*p[str1[i-1]-'a'][str1[i]-'a'])%MOD;
            h2=(h2*p[str2[i-1]-'a'][str2[i]-'a'])%MOD;
        }
        if(next1[i+1]+next2[i+1]>=i&&
        h1*p[str1[i]-'a'][str1[0]-'a']==
        h2*p[str2[i]-'a'][str2[0]-'a'])stk.push(i+1);
    }
    while(!stk.empty()){
        if(check(stk.top())){ans=stk.top();break;}
        stk.pop();
    }
    printf("%d\n",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

PS:There may be no O(n) solution to this problem , O(n) solution exists only when one of the strings is its the minimum representation.

Comment: I don't see a question

Comment: What is the size of two strings?

Comment: No longer than 2,000,000

Comment: Any other constraints? number of character?

Comment: Only lower case letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this  using following method :-

```
1. Find longest prefix for each substring string1[0 to i] which are also suffix for substring string2[0 to i] and visa versa.Lets call them lps1[i] & lps2[i].
2. if lps1[i] + lps2[i] == i+1 then prefix upto i is isomorphic

example :-

string1 = "abcdx" 
string2 = "cdabz"

lps1[0] = 0
lps2[0] = 0

lps1[1] = 0
lps2[1] = 0

lps1[2] = 1
lps2[2] = 1

lps1[3] = 2
lps2[3] = 2

lps1[4] = 0
lps2[4] = 0

lps1[3] + lps2[3] = 4 = 3+1 hence the largest prefix isomorphic is of length 3+1 = 4
```

**Now main question is how to find lps efficiently ?**

[KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) uses a similar algorithm to build a table in `O(|S|)`. Check the part **table-building algorithm** it basically constructs lps for string with itself but you can replace

```
if W[pos - 1] = W[cnd]
```

**by:-**

```
if string1[ pos-1 ] = string2[cnd]  

with some corner checks like cnd < string2.length
```

**Time complexity :-**

```
Build LPS arrays : O(|S1|+|S2|)

check isomorphic prefix : O(min(|S1|,|S2|)
```

**Here is c++ implementation :-**

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>



void ComputeLPS(char* str1,char* str2,int n,int LPS[]) {
  LPS[0] = 0;
  int len = 0,i=1;
  while(i<n){
    if(str2[len]==str1[i]) {
      len++;
      LPS[i] = len;
      i++;
    }
    else {

      if(len!=0) {
    len = LPS[len-1];
      }
      else {
    LPS[i] = 0;
    i++;
      }
    }

  }



}


int isomorphic_prefix(char* str1,char* str2) {

  int n = strlen(str1);
  int lps1[n];
  int lps2[n];

  ComputeLPS(str1,str2,n,lps1);
  ComputeLPS(str2,str1,n,lps2);
  int max = 0;

  for(int i = 0;i < n;i++) {

    int k = lps1[i]+lps2[i];

    if(k==i)
      max = i+1;
  }

  return max;

}



int main() {

  char str1[100];
  char str2[100];

  gets(str1);
  gets(str2);

  printf("max isomorphic prefix : %d",isomorphic_prefix(str1,str2));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain about how prefix of string 1 should be suffix of string 2? for OP's example case, the longest length of the prefix which is also suffix is 0.

Comment: @PhamTrung I think you didnt get my point i have evaluated longest prefix which is also suffix for substrings [0 to i] in an array lps[i]

Comment: @PhamTrung check my example

Comment: Hmm, How about the case abcdx and abcdy ?And how to determine the longest prefix for each index? this task should take another O(N), which is in total O(N^2)

Comment: @PhamTrung lps1[0] = 1 lps2[0] = 1 , lps1[1] = 2 lps2[1] = 2 ..... lps1[4] = 0 lps2[4] = 0 hence max is i = 3 hence ans = 3+1 = 4

Comment: @Pham Trung i have given a wiki link of KMP which evaluates in O(N) using dynamic programming

Comment: How to use KMP to search for longest prefix in this case? it is a search for word algorithm. For example, it can search for ab in cdab, but how can you tell ab is the longest prefix?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55960/discussion-between-vikram-bhat-and-pham-trung).

Comment: actually according to the code ,my lps1 is {-1,0,1,2} but lps2 is {-1,0,0,1} , are you sure the KMP table-building process is right???

Comment: @NKWBTB for which problem ?

Comment: @NKWBTB lps1 and 2 is not the KMP table, you need to process s1 and s2 using KMP to build lps1 and 2.

Comment: yeah I changed the algorithm according to your solution,but after test two test case are wrong

Comment: @NKWBTB post it in your question and use the `{}` code button. It will avoid down vote for you too :)

Comment: @Vikram Bhat is it necessary to check the corners if the length of the two strings are the same

Comment: @NKWBTB In wiki code the indexes start from 1 hence W[0] = -1 but you dont need to do that you start from 0 hence next[0] = 0 is sufficient

Comment: @NKWBTB i have post an implementation similar to what you have done crosscheck with it

Comment: @Vikram Bhat  I modified my code but there is still wrong test cases. Is there still some corners I have not checked???

Comment: @NKWBTB no there are no corner case but i think lps[i] actually stores lps of substring[0 to i-1] instead of [0 to i] so you need to check lps1[i-1]+lps2[i-1] instead and more sum > i not equal to it as you have done and ans = i+1 as you want length of prefix

Comment: I know why it's wrong .There is a bug in this solution. KMP only find max match length but you can't prove the match is a prefix in string2.so the answer can be bigger than the maxlength.

Comment: @NKWBTB what is the bug ?

Comment: can you give an example of that ?

Comment: Try this case: dcdcdc and cdcdc, result should be 4

Comment: @PhamTrung i think i got the bug the first LPS is fine the second one needs to  do something else such that it only checks prefix of particular length not the longest.

Comment: uhm, not sure, I am thinking about that too, but there is no guarantee that the first part should be the longest prefix, it is just too greedy

Comment: @PhamTrung oh yes it is , i think its a job for a DP but how in O(N) seems impossible

Comment: @Vikram Bhat Oh I was wrong , i mean that the max matxh can not gurantee that it is a suffix of string2[0....p]

Comment: @NKWBTB I also think my solution is wrong , the problem require a DP , my solution is greedy. The division of strings can be anywhere. My solution also accepts wrong permutations

Comment: @Vikram Bhat NO I think your solution is right , but KMP is not correct. We may need other algorithm or data structure.

Comment: @Vikram Bhat Oh it's a wrong solution .I know it now ..... "bcda" and "cdab" is example

Comment: @Vikram Bhat The person who made this problem ,his solution is very similar to yours.But actually this solution is right only when one of the strings is its the minimum representation.He made a wrong problem.So n^2 may be the correct solution to this problem.Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I thought a lot on this problem and what i got is that this problem is simpler than we thought. According to me you can solve this by keeping links `(a,b)` which suggests character `a` precedes `b` in a circular permutation. If the all links of `string1` and `string2` are same then it means they are the same circular permutation. The trick here is to give a link `(a,b)` **+1** value for string1 and **-1** for string2 hence if all links are same then all pairs `(a,b)` will have zero count. This can be achieved using pair count `arr[26][26] for all alphabet pairs` where `arr[a][b]` represents number of net links `(a,b)` are there in difference of the two permutations.

**Proof that circular permutation can fully be represented by set of links :-**

**Consider a circular permutation :-**

x0->x1->x2->x3->x0

**representation in set of links :-** `(x0,x1),(x1,x2),(x2,x3),(x3,x0)`

**The claim is that this set of links always represents the above permutation only.**

We will prove this by contradiction. Lets assume that there is a different circular permutation that can be represented by same set of links. Then there can be different circular permutation that be formed by swapping two characters.

**We swap x1 and x3 then we get permutation:-**

```
x0->x3->x2->x1->x0

**set of links :-** (x0,x3),(x3,x2),(x2,x1),(x1,x0)

There are two possibilities :-

1. x1 == x3 then new permutation is same as old so there is contradiction here.
2. x1 != x3 then (x0,x3) != (x0,x1) , (x3,x0) != (x1,x0) hence again there is contradiction.


This result can be extended to multiple swaps.
```

Hence it is proved by contradiction that set of links represent only one circular permutation.

**Using this result i have written the following c++ implementation :-**

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>

inline int getval(char ch) {

 return ch-'a'; 
}



int isomorphic_prefix(char* str1,char* str2) {

 int edges[26][26] = {0};
 int n = strlen(str1);
 int isoprefix = 0;
 int simedges = 676;
 int first1 = getval(str1[0]);
 int first2 = getval(str2[0]);

 for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {


    int prev1,prev2;
    if(i>0) {
        prev1 = getval(str1[i-1]);
        prev2 = getval(str2[i-1]);
    }


    int curr1 = getval(str1[i]);
    int curr2 = getval(str2[i]);

    if(i > 0) {
        if(edges[prev1][first1] == 1)
            simedges++;
        else if(edges[prev1][first1] == 0)
            simedges--;
        edges[prev1][first1]--;
        if(edges[prev2][first2] == -1)
            simedges++;
        else if(edges[prev2][first2] == 0)
            simedges--;
        edges[prev2][first2]++;
        if(edges[prev1][curr1] == 0)
            simedges--;
        else if(edges[prev1][curr1] == -1)
            simedges++;
        edges[prev1][curr1]++;
        if(edges[prev2][curr2] == 0)
            simedges--;
        else if(edges[prev2][curr2] == 1)
            simedges++;
        edges[prev2][curr2]--;

    }

    if(edges[curr1][first1]==0)
        simedges--;
    else if(edges[curr1][first1] == -1)
            simedges++;
    edges[curr1][first1]++;

    if(edges[curr2][first2]==0)
        simedges--;
    else if(edges[curr2][first2] == 1)
            simedges++;
    edges[curr2][first2]--;

    if(simedges == 676)
        isoprefix = i+1;
 }

 return isoprefix;

}




int main() {
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];
    gets(str1);
    gets(str2);
    printf("%d",isomorphic_prefix(str1,str2));
    return 0;   
}
```

**Time Complexity :-**

As you can see in the implementation it is a single loop of **O(N)** with constant calculations inside hence it is **O(N)**.

Comment: Actually I think it is wrong.Like this example "aabaaaab" and "aaaaabab" their represents are the same.

Comment: I mixed your solutions into a enumerate+check solution. first use KMP to search the answer and use the algorithm below to abandon some incorrect position then check these possible position from back to front with brute force(KMP).I passed all the test.Though the algorithm is correct,its worst time complexity is O(n^2). I still wander if there is a correct O(n) algorithm.

Comment: If we consider swap of a series ***aaa->set(x1,x2).....set(x2,x1)->aaa*** move it ***aa-set(x1,x2)......set(x2,x1)-aaaa actually their represent are the same in your program,but they are not isomorphic_prefix